# Can I give vitamin k 25mg on same day as Baytril?

Tags: medicines

She will be having a CT/Rhinscopy on Thurs. in five days but still has one day of Baytril. She needs five days to complete Vit. K to get her blood to clot. I need to start it today also.

Comment: what type of pet do you have? it might not be important to know to answer this question but to make it searchable it is.

Answer (score 1):

This type of question is best directed to your veterinarian, who is familiar with your pet's case and prescribed medications.

Per Plumb's Veterinary Drugs, there are no reported interactions between Baytril (enrofloxacin) and Vitamin K. These medications are in general very safe to use together and commonly prescribed at the same time.